# Intercept pointer event is UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a 5 inch display and want to calibrate it in windows iot core.
the LCD touch is worked, but is not correctly calibrated, in other word, when a point is touched on the screen, the X,Y of point is not truly aligned on the application form.

I have the calibration algorithm but i want a solution to generally handle this in my application, like this:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += CoreWindow_PointerPressed;

    private void CoreWindow_PointerPressed(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.PointerEventArgs args)
    {
        Point touchedPoint = args.CurrentPoint.Position;        //get the current touched point
        Point calibratedPoint = Calibrate(touchedPoint);        //run the calibration algorithm on the point and get new point

        //raise new calibratedPoint (as a Pointer pressed) to the application window
    }
```

How can i raise the new calibrated point to the application window?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here. Can you share an example?

Comment: I edit my post and add a sample code. generally i want to know how can is intercept the pointer events and change the default touched position over the application?

Comment: You said you have  calibration algorithm to calculate the correct position, what else you want to do ? What "How can i raise the new calibrated point to the application window?" mean? What things you want to set with the  calibrated pointer? What " allined " you mean above?

Comment: When we work with a not calibrated LCD, a touch point is not correctly map on the application form, for example when a button is touched, the touch point position is not truly placed on the button. Now, i have a calibration algorithm, mean that i can get a touched point and pass it through the algorithm and calculate the correct point, BUT the main question is: How can i apply this new point as a replacement of the old?